# Github cannot make Pull Request from base branch

Tags: git, github, branch, git-branch, pull-request

When I'm trying to make a Pull Request FROM default branch (which is master in my case). I'm not allowed to do it, UI is blocking me to do it without any warning etc.

[image: not allowed to make PR from default]

It's because master is my default branch:
[image: default branch as master]

But when I change default branch (to not be master in my case). I'm allowed to create Pull Request, which wasn't possible to create when master was default branch:
[image: able to crate PR from master]

I know that I was able to do such things in past so something changed not so far ago. Does anyone know how to create Pull Requests from default branch in that case? I was looking into repository setting but I wasn't able to find anything connected with that.

Answer (score 4):

The problem was that title is not automatically fulfilled for default branch...
when you fulfill title button will be unlocked.

Browser inspect FTW! :)